# How to get Windows Store(not local) Account Name in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp

I m currently developing a UWP app, and i want to get the user's Name, from the store(for analytics).

I want to save it in a database and update the DateTime when the app opens, which will give me the app insights. How i can get the User's name on Windows Store Account(or a unique ID to separate the User from others).
I dont want to save the local account name, as it described at other quesions here.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could save a file containing your unique ID to the `ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder` folder. This folder is synced across all devices of the same user, and therefore allows you do your insights. You could also check out hockeyapp (https://www.hockeyapp.net/) if you want a library to do the insights for you

Comment: Hopefully waiting the [Azure Mobile](http://mobile.azure.com) to support uwp apps, because i think it is the next level of hockeyapp, so i m going to write these data to a db for now. Also, searching for 'ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder' in the documentation seems that it doesnt return something unique. Do you know which property i should use? Thanks!

Comment: Its just a normal folder; So you can create a file `user_id` which you fill with a Guid to identify your user. I'm gonna make an example shortly

Comment: Ok, post it as answer, to mark this as answered! Thanks, thanks, thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder` to store information you want to persist for your user. To be able to distinguish between different users save a unique id to this folder, and you're good to go!

```
public async Task<string> GetUserIdAsync()
{
    var fileName = "user_id";
    var folder = ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder;
    var file = await folder.TryGetItemAsync(fileName);
    if (file == null)
    {
        //if file does not exist we create a new guid
        var storageFile = await folder.CreateFileAsync(fileName);
        var newId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(storageFile, newId);
        return newId;
    }
    else
    {
        //else we return the already exising guid
        var storageFile = await folder.GetFileAsync(fileName);
        return await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(storageFile);
    }
}
```